# What does i**=2 mean in python? does it 2^i=i?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def f()
   i=2
   while i<len(l)
   i**=2
```

What does
    i**=2
mean in python? Does it 2^i=i?

Comment: Please make sure to always post code that is syntactically valid, *especially* if you're asking a question about syntax.

Answer (score 5):

`i **= 2` uses an augmented assignment with a power operator. For numbers (and other immutable objects), it is the same as:

```
i = i ** 2
```

storing the square of `i` in `i`. The [`**` operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator) is the power operator, returning the left-hand operand to the power of the right-hand operand.

[`**=` assignment](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) is the *augmented* assignment version of that operator. It gives the left-hand operand the chance to apply changes in-line, if the object is mutable. For immutable objects it makes for a nice compact notation.

Your sample code snippet is not valid Python; you need to mind your indentation (the `while` block requires another level) and you are missing the `:` colons for both the `def` statement and the `while` statement:

```
def f():
    i = 2
    while i < len(l):
        i **= 2
```

Presumably the function will do something more with `i` or return the result.

Comment: unlike some other languages `^` is `xor` in Python (not `pow`)